# How to fix gcc error produced by pip install?

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install a python package from PyPI with the following command

```
sudo pip3 install switcheo
```

The installation fails and show this error message:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_SYSCTL_HW_USERMEM=1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1 -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto -Iscrypt-1.2.1/lib/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/cpusupport -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util -Iscrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/asprintf.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/asprintf.o
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/scrypt.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix_sse2.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt_smix.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/lib/crypto/crypto_scrypt.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/lib/scryptenc/scryptenc_cpuperf.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/lib/util/memlimit.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/alg/sha256.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes_aesni.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aes.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_aesctr.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/crypto/crypto_entropy.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/entropy.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/insecure_memzero.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/warnp.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/humansize.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/scrypt-1.2.1/libcperciva/util/asprintf.o -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/_scrypt.cpython-37m-darwin.so
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-install-2cof4cvu/scrypt/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-1ecvxjh1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-2cof4cvu/scrypt/
```

Answer (score 3):

Install the `libssl-dev` package

On Ubuntu, it's as simple as `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`

On mac, you need to install `openssl`: `brew install openssl`

If that doesn't work, you need to install `Homebrew`. You should use `Homebrew`, it makes installing much easier.

If that still doesn't work, you can install `libssl-dev` and make a symlink:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2p/lib/libssl.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I'm using python3.8 and MacOS 14.4.  I also tried `brew reintall openssl1@1.11`